# Relatively compact sets in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}^{d}_{0}$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Reading an article I came across the following line, which botheres me since quite a while.

Let $E:=\bar{\mathbb{R}}^{d}_{0}:=([-\infty,0)\cup(0,+\infty])^d$ be the closure of $\mathbb{R}^d$ without ${0}$. Then - so the claim - a set $B\subseteq E$ is relatively compact if and only if it is bounded away from $0$. 
I mean obviously such a set $B$ doesn't have to be bounded above, hence it's closure cannot be bounded too. Why isn't that a problem? In $\mathbb{R^d}$ or $\mathbb{R^d}/\{0\}$ it most certainly would be one, so why and how does adding the "infinity"-points changes that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a problem because $(a,\infty]$ is an open set for any $a\in \mathbb{R_{+}}$ - so you need only one open set to cover a "large" portion of the set. In particular, even if a set $B$ is unbounded, you can make it bounded by removing $B\setminus (1,\infty]$. What remains will now be bounded, but removing this set does not change the relative compactness of $B$.

Comment: Ok, probably I got your argument after starring at it for far too long. Guess the heart of your post is, that any open cover of an unbounded set, e.g. $(a,\infty]$, must contain an open set of the form $(b,\infty]$, to cover the point infinity. Hence the rest is bounded and makes no problem. But still I'm not feeling safe with this argument, since why do I know, that ANY open cover has to contain such a "large" open set?

Comment: Because if $\infty$ is a point in your set, then any open cover of that set must have a member which contains $\infty$, and so contains $(a,\infty]$ for some $a>0$.

Comment: ok, that seems reasonable and I will give it some more thoughs. Thank's a lot for your help!